# Make "Counter Increment" hidden onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make a `counter-increment` not visible and being able to toggle on and off the `counter-increment` property? For example, please see the attached code. Thank you!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/Lcbdxhk5/)

```css
body{
    counter-reset:chapter;
}

h2{
    counter-reset:topic;
}

h2:before{
    counter-increment:chapter;
    content:counter(chapter) ". ";
}

h4:before {
    counter-increment:topic;
    content:counter(chapter) "." counter(topic) " ";
}
```

```html
<button>
Toggle On/Off Counter Increment Property
</button>

<h2>Paragraph</h2>
<h4>
   Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
    Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
   Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
   Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
  Sentence
</h4>
```

Comment: Have you heard of classes maybe ...?

Comment: You're looking for the javascript code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Basicly ou can reset the :before rules :

```
button:focus ~ :before {content:'';/* erase counter */}
button:focus {pointer-events:none; /* to toggle focus */}
```

Basic snippet CSS example to show the idea *(or fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lcbdxhk5/1/ + toggle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcbdxhk5/3/ )*:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: topic;
}

h2:before {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: counter(chapter) ". ";
}

h4:before {
  counter-increment: topic;
  content: counter(chapter) "." counter(topic) " ";
}

button:focus ~:before {
  content: '';
}
button:focus {pointer-events:none; /* to toggle focus */}
```

```html
<button>
  Toggle On/Off Counter Increment Property
</button>

<h2>Paragraph</h2>
<h4>
   Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
    Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
   Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
   Sentence
</h4>
<h4>
  Sentence
</h4>
```

Via js/jQuery, just use the `toggle()` jQuery fonction adding/removing a class

Comment: However, this does not work for pseudo elements with a class used instead of specifying only the element, for example <h4>. Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Dave can you set a fiddle(or update your question) with your elements and class and add also numbers you wish to see produced by the counter. Basicly, the selector would turn to be `button:focus ~ h4.MyClass:before` if these are the ones you want to filter off.